# Kafka State Store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

If there are two Kafka stream consuming from same Kafka topic ,in Fault tolerance case if one Kafka stream went down then Kafka state store will get replicated in second Kafka stream. if first come back what will happen to the State store of second Kafka stream .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the failing instance comes back, another rebalance will be triggered and some tasks will get migrated to this recovering instance. It's difficult to predict what task will be migrated though -- it can happen, that the store is migrated back. But there are many runtime dependencies that influence what tasks will be migrated. In any case, the "old store" is most likely corrupted after the failure and Streams will wipe it out most likely (and recreate from scratch if it gets migrated back).